# Getting the event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a href link , when I click this link, it pop-up a lightbox to play a youtube video, how do I know which event listener it is triggered if I turn on the Chrome Developer Tools? I want to know which javascript function will be executed when I click.

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Comment: try window.event should give you event name

Comment: Thanks Ashish Balchandani but I could not catch your meaning, how do I try?

Comment: you can alert(window.event) in your code or you can use debugger and debug the value in developer tools

Comment: Actually there are lot of javascript function called loaded and difficult to add every functions with alert(window.event) in code block.

Comment: can you post your code here or probably fiddle

Comment: <a rel="wp-video-lightbox" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmbVmc4JAt4&amp;width=640&amp;height=480" title="">Watch Top Notch 80's Hong Kong Trailer</a>
When click on this link, a popup lightbox and play the video instead of changing the browser's URL. I don't know what function is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58544/discussion-between-user3059850-and-ashish-balchandani).